# Using 32 bit dll in 64 bit XAMPP

Tags: php, dll, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I want to use `zkemkeeper.dll` in my PHP web application.

I already copied the `dll` files in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and registered using `regsvr32 zkemkeeper.dll`.

Registration is successful, and I was able to connect to zk device using the XAMPP 32-bit.

```
$obj = new COM("zkemkeeper.ZKEM");
```

But after installing latest XAMPP 64-bit, I am getting the error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `zkemkeeper.ZKEM': Class not registered
```

I also enabled the `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` extension.

After many searches and studies, what I understood is, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit module into its process space.

It would be great if anyone can help me with any work around or solution.

Comment: Use a 64-bit version of your DLL, or apparently you could write a wrapper program that can communicate via COM; see the linked duplicate.